# Orthographic camera and zoom controls in SceneKit

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, scenekit

When using a camera with `myCameraNode.camera.usesOrthographicProjection = YES;`, as far as I can tell you can't zoom as you normally would using the default controls given by `myScene.allowsCameraControl = YES;` – the only way to zoom that I can tell is by changing `myCameraNode.scale = (SCNVector3*)...`

Is there a way to somehow bind the scroll wheel to this scale parameter, while retaining the standard camera controls for rotation/translation? Or to otherwise 'fix' the default camera controls?

Edit: I think I'm misunderstanding how the camera works. The two-finger zoom gesture *does* still work with orthographic projection, but it seems like it only lets me zoom out and not let me zoom in any further. I suspect it may be related to the `myCameraNode.scale`, but if I don't set that parameter the objects in my scene are huge and I only see a tiny fraction of it (and the larger the `scale` the smaller my objects get).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in camera controls on `SCNView` are pretty basic, probably best used only for debugging. For a production app, it's better to control the camera yourself, especially if you're using orthographic projection. Set up your own event handling that controls the `orthographicScale` property of the camera, and you're set.

---

Followup on comment:

The `scale` property on `SCNNode` controls how big a node's content is relative to its parent node — it's a coordinate space transformation, just like `rotation` and `position`. It's not really appropriate for implementing camera zoom. In a perspective projection, you use the camera's `xFov` and/or `yFov` properties to zoom (and I presume that's what the built-in camera controls do). The API doesn't define what the controls do for an orthographic camera, so anything you observe about its behavior is probably undefined and might be a bug... you might not be able to rely on it staying that way.

If there's more you'd like the built-in camera controls to handle, I'd recommend [filing an enhancement request](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: I might well have to do this, but one of the appeals of SceneKit is that I don't have to e.g. write my own event handling. The default camera is almost perfect, so it seems a shame to re-write it. My specific issue here is that I think I don't understand what `.scale` property actually does: why do the objects get smaller as scale increases? And why can I zoom out from the default zoom level but not zoom in further than initial zoom level? If I could find a way to calculate what `.scale` should be for my scene I'd be set, rather than guessing/hard-coding, which is what I'm doing at present.